# Is there a way to use a Random Forest model on Android to make predictions?

Tags: android, machine-learning, weka, random-forest

I've been looking at primarily Weka to do machine learning testing, and I've found that Random Forest models have the best results for my purposes. I wanted to save this model and implement it on Android to predict new values, but these days it seems nigh-impossible to implement Weka on Android (all the available sources are super out-dated).

Are there any ways to train a Random Forest model, and then implement that model on an Android app to predict new values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Weka, you can train Random Forest (RF) models also with R, Scikit-Learn or Apache Spark ML. You can export/convert RF models from their native representation into the standardized PMML representation using [R2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml), [SkLearn2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) or [JPMML-SparkML-Package](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml-package) tools, respectively, and then import and score such models using Java PMML scoring engines such as [JPMML-Evaluator](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator). The latter has a direct Android integration available.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Is this the Android integration you're referring to: https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-android ?

Comment: @Yuerno Yes, that's the one. It's a bit behind the JPMML-Evaluator library development cycle, but it would be trivial to upgrade it yourself.

Comment: What would be the process in upgrading the Android integration? Or should I ask that as an entirely separate question?

Comment: The current state of the Andoid integration should be perfectly fine for your use case - the representation and scoring of Random Forest models is very basic stuff.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a shot. Thank you!

Comment: Hi again. I just wanted to follow up to ask a couple questions on the process flow for JPMML. I've created the PMML model using Python; is the next step to use JPMML-Evaluator, then JPMML-Android, or do I directly use JPMML-Android with this PMML model?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of user1808924, you can convert Weka Random Forest to PMML using the following tool:

https://github.com/AlbertoCasasOrtiz/weka-to-pmml

And then proceed to load the PMML models in Android.